# Azure Service Bus SubscriptionClient high latency / not receiving messages concurrently

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

If I send a batch of messages to a Topic, and read messages using a Subscription client, then I seem to receive messages *sequentially*, i.e. OnMessageAsync is fired for each message sent, however there is a noticeable (150+ millisecond) delay between each receive-event

**Sender**:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("blah");
sender = factory.CreateMessageSender("MyTopicName");

var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    tasks.Add(sender.SendAsync(new BrokeredMessage("My Message"))
       .ContinueWith(t => Log("Sent Message {i}"));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);  // This completes within a few millis
```

**Receiver**:

```
receiver = factory.CreateSubscriptionClient("MyTopicName", "MySubscription");
_sbClient.OnMessageAsync(async message =>
{
    var msg = message.GetBody<string>();
    Log("Received message xxxx
    await message.CompleteAsync();
});
```

This means that the 10th message sent is only received more than 1.5 seconds after it was sent.

An Azure latency test shows about a 200ms latency to the datacenter I'm using, so  I'm not expecting messages to come back before that (and indeed the first message is received shortly after this), however I wouldn't expect the 'cumulative' behavior I'm seeing.

Playing around with MaxConcurrentCalls and adding a delay in the OnMessageAsync, shows this working as expected, and I can see only MaxConcurrentCalls being processed at a time

I've messed around with **DeleteOnReceive** modes, enabling '**Express**', disabling '**Partitioning**', using **AMQP** rather than SBMP etc., however nothing really seems to make much difference.

[I'm Using Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0]

**EDIT:**
Here's what the log looks like. So if I send 10 messages at the same time, I'll only receive the 10th message 1.5 seconds after I sent it:

> 18:09:32.624  Sent message 0
>   18:09:32.624  Sent message 1
>   18:09:32.641  Sent message 2
>   18:09:32.641  Sent message 3
>   18:09:32.674  Sent message 4
>   18:09:32.674  Sent message 5
>   18:09:32.709  Sent message 6
>   18:09:32.709  Sent message 7
>   18:09:32.738  Sent message 8
>   18:09:32.738  Sent message 9
>
> 18:09:32.791  Received message 1 in 341 millis
>   18:09:32.950  Received message 2 in 487 millis
>   18:09:33.108  Received message 3 in 628 millis
>   18:09:33.265  Received message 4 in 770 millis
>   18:09:33.426  Received message 5 in 914 millis
>   18:09:33.586  Received message 6 in 1060 millis
>   18:09:33.745  Received message 7 in 1202 millis
>   18:09:33.906  Received message 8 in 1347 millis
>   18:09:34.065  Received message 9 in 1492 millis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging into how exactly the **OnMessage** message pump worked I realised that this is actually a *polling* mechanism, where the underlying call to ServiceBus is still a 'Receive()' that attempts to **pull** any new message(s). If that times out, the call is done again ad infinitum.
The behaviour I was seeing then made sense if that call to Receive() **only returned a single message**, and then required a150ms roundtrip to retrieve the next one etc.

Enter the **[PrefetchCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.prefetchcount?view=azure-dotnet)**. Setting this to a nonzero value on the SubscriptionClient effectively permits the underlying Receive() to pull down multiple messages, that are then cached and made (immediately) available for bubbling into OnMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're processing messages *much* faster than Service Bus can deliver new ones. Azure SB is relatively slow on an individual-message basis. Verify this by adding a `Task.Delay` before completion and log the thread IDs, and you should see multiple copies spin up.

Comment: If I'm sending messages concurrently, I'd expect to receive them with a similar level of concurrency. I can't believe ASB performance is this poor...it must be configuration / my implementation!

Comment: I've found that Service Bus delivery performance can vary wildly, but it's never particularly fast (just "much slower" from time to time). Plenty of others have reached the same conclusion over the years. Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162824/152997) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818683/152997).